# How to detect geometric symbols in a image (python)?

Tags: python, ocr

I´m working with multiple api and OCR libraries for python. I extract the text perfectly but I need to extract a series of symbols defined by "X", as demonstrated in the following image.
Is there any particular library I should use or any specific configuration to be able to extract it?

I can use any free python library available

[image]